# This query has no error, but it's also not providing any output

Tags: sql, mysql

```
    -- Drop the Employees table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Employees;

-- Create the Employees table
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    empID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR(50),
    lastName VARCHAR(50),
    jobTitle VARCHAR(50),
    hiredDate DATE,
    salary DECIMAL(10,2)
);

-- Insert 20 records into the Employees table
INSERT INTO Employees (firstName, lastName, jobTitle, hiredDate, salary)
VALUES 
('John', 'Doe', 'Manager', '2023-01-01', 60000.00),
('Jane', 'Smith', 'Developer', '2023-02-01', 50000.00),
('Bob', 'Johnson', 'Analyst', '2023-03-01', 45000.00),
('Alice', 'Davis', 'Developer', '2023-04-01', 50000.00),
('Charlie', 'Miller', 'Manager', '2023-05-01', 60000.00),
('Dave', 'Wilson', 'Analyst', '2023-06-01', 45000.00),
('Emily', 'Moore', 'Developer', '2023-07-01', 50000.00),
('Frank', 'Taylor', 'Manager', '2023-08-01', 60000.00),
('Grace', 'Anderson', 'Analyst', '2023-09-01', 45000.00),
('Henry', 'Thomas', 'Developer', '2023-10-01', 50000.00),
('Ivy', 'Jackson', 'Manager', '2023-11-01', 60000.00),
('Jack', 'White', 'Analyst', '2023-12-01', 45000.00),
('Kelly', 'Harris', 'Developer', '2024-01-01', 50000.00),
('Leo', 'Clark', 'Manager', '2024-02-01', 60000.00),
('Mia', 'Lewis', 'Analyst', '2024-03-01', 45000.00),
('Nathan', 'Lee', 'Developer', '2024-04-01', 50000.00),
('Olivia', 'Walker', 'Manager', '2024-05-01', 60000.00),
('Paul', 'Hall', 'Analyst', '2024-06-01', 45000.00),
('Quincy', 'Allen', 'Developer', '2024-07-01', 50000.00),
('Rita', 'Young', 'Manager', '2024-08-01', 60000.00);

-- Drop the Skills table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Skills;

-- Create the Skills table
CREATE TABLE Skills (
    skillID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    skillName VARCHAR(50),
    category VARCHAR(50),
    description TEXT
);

-- Insert 20 records into the Skills table
INSERT INTO Skills (skillName, category, description)
VALUES 
('Java Programming', 'Technical', 'Ability to develop applications using Java'),
('Python Programming', 'Technical', 'Ability to develop applications using Python'),
('Project Management', 'Management', 'Ability to manage projects effectively'),
('Data Analysis', 'Technical', 'Ability to analyze data and extract insights'),
('Communication', 'Soft Skill', 'Ability to communicate effectively with team members'),
('SQL Database Management', 'Technical', 'Ability to manage databases using SQL'),
('Web Development', 'Technical', 'Ability to develop websites using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript'),
('Graphic Design', 'Creative', 'Ability to create visual concepts using graphic design tools'),
('Digital Marketing', 'Marketing', 'Ability to create and manage digital marketing campaigns'),
('Network Management', 'Technical', 'Ability to manage and maintain network systems'),
('Cloud Computing', 'Technical', 'Ability to work with cloud computing platforms like AWS, Azure'),
('Mobile App Development', 'Technical', 'Ability to develop mobile applications for Android and iOS'),
('Customer Service', 'Soft Skill', 'Ability to provide excellent customer service'),
('Sales and Marketing', 'Marketing', 'Ability to sell products and services effectively'),
('Human Resource Management', 'Management', 'Ability to manage human resources effectively'),
('Financial Analysis', 'Finance', 'Ability to analyze financial data and create reports'),
('Supply Chain Management', 'Management', 'Ability to manage supply chains effectively'),
('Quality Assurance', 'Technical', 'Ability to ensure the quality of products and services'),
('Leadership', 'Soft Skill', 'Ability to lead teams and projects effectively'),
('Time Management', 'Soft Skill', 'Ability to manage time effectively and meet deadlines');

-- Drop the Jobs table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Jobs;

-- Create the Jobs table
CREATE TABLE Jobs (
    jobID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    jobTitle VARCHAR(50),
    minSalary DECIMAL(10,2),
    maxSalary DECIMAL(10,2)
);

-- Insert 20 records into the Jobs table
INSERT INTO Jobs (jobTitle, minSalary, maxSalary)
VALUES 
('Software Developer', 50000.00, 70000.00),
('Project Manager', 60000.00, 80000.00),
('Data Analyst', 45000.00, 65000.00),
('Network Administrator', 50000.00, 70000.00),
('Database Administrator', 50000.00, 70000.00),
('Web Developer', 45000.00, 65000.00),
('Graphic Designer', 40000.00, 60000.00),
('Digital Marketing Specialist', 45000.00, 65000.00),
('Sales Manager', 55000.00, 75000.00),
('Customer Service Representative', 35000.00, 55000.00),
('Human Resources Manager', 60000.00, 80000.00),
('Financial Analyst', 50000.00, 70000.00),
('Supply Chain Manager', 60000.00, 80000.00),
('Quality Assurance Engineer', 50000.00, 70000.00),
('Technical Support Specialist', 40000.00, 60000.00),
('Mobile App Developer', 50000.00, 70000.00),
('Cloud Computing Specialist', 55000.00, 75000.00),
('SEO Specialist', 45000.00, 65000.00),
('Content Writer', 40000.00, 60000.00),
('Social Media Manager', 45000.00, 65000.00);

-- Drop the JobSkills table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS JobSkills;

-- Create the JobSkills table
CREATE TABLE JobSkills (
    jobSkillID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    jobID INT,
    skillID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (jobID) REFERENCES Jobs(jobID),
    FOREIGN KEY (skillID) REFERENCES Skills(skillID)
);

-- Insert 20 records into the JobSkills table
INSERT INTO JobSkills (jobID, skillID)
VALUES 
(1, 1), (1, 6), (1, 7),  -- Software Developer skills
(2, 3), (2, 19), (2, 20), -- Project Manager skills
(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 20),  -- Data Analyst skills
(4, 10), (4, 11), (4, 20), -- Network Administrator skills
(5, 6), (5, 11), (5, 20),  -- Database Administrator skills
(6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 20),   -- Web Developer skills
(7, 8), (7, 19), (7, 20),  -- Graphic Designer skills
(8, 9), (8, 18), (8, 20),  -- Digital Marketing Specialist skills
(9, 13), (9, 14), (9, 20), -- Sales Manager skills
(10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 20); -- Customer Service Representative skills

-- Drop the Applicants table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Applicants;

-- Create the Applicants table
CREATE TABLE Applicants (
    applicantID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR(50),
    lastName VARCHAR(50),
    appliedJobID INT,
    applicationDate DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (appliedJobID) REFERENCES Jobs(jobID)
);

-- Insert 20 records into the Applicants table
INSERT INTO Applicants (firstName, lastName, appliedJobID, applicationDate)
VALUES 
('Anna', 'Brown', 1, '2023-09-01'),
('Ben', 'Carter', 2, '2023-09-02'),
('Catherine', 'Davis', 3, '2023-09-03'),
('Daniel', 'Evans', 4, '2023-09-04'),
('Ella', 'Foster', 5, '2023-09-05'),
('Finn', 'Green', 6, '2023-09-06'),
('Grace', 'Harris', 7, '2023-09-07'),
('Henry', 'Ivanov', 8, '2023-09-08'),
('Isabella', 'Johnson', 9, '2023-09-09'),
('Jack', 'King', 10, '2023-09-10'),
('Katie', 'Lewis', 11, '2023-09-11'),
('Liam', 'Martin', 12, '2023-09-12'),
('Mia', 'Nelson', 13, '2023-09-13'),
('Noah', 'Owen', 14, '2023-09-14'),
('Olivia', 'Perez', 15, '2023-09-15'),
('Parker', 'Quinn', 16, '2023-09-16'),
('Quincy', 'Roberts', 17, '2023-09-17'),
('Ryan', 'Smith', 18, '2023-09-18'),
('Sophia', 'Taylor', 19, '2023-09-19'),
('Thomas', 'Upton', 20, '2023-09-20');

-- Drop the ApplicantSkills table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ApplicantSkills;

-- Create the ApplicantSkills table
CREATE TABLE ApplicantSkills (
    applicantSkillID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    applicantID INT,
    skillID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (applicantID)
        REFERENCES Applicants (applicantID),
    FOREIGN KEY (skillID)
        REFERENCES Skills (skillID)
);

-- Insert 20 records into the ApplicantSkills table
INSERT INTO ApplicantSkills (applicantID, skillID)
VALUES 
(1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 20),  -- Skills for applicant 1
(2, 3), (2, 19), (2, 20), -- Skills for applicant 2
(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 20),  -- Skills for applicant 3
(4, 10), (4, 11), (4, 20), -- Skills for applicant 4
(5, 6), (5, 11), (5, 20),  -- Skills for applicant 5
(6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 20),   -- Skills for applicant 6
(7, 8), (7, 19), (7, 20),  -- Skills for applicant 7
(8, 9), (8, 18), (8, 20),  -- Skills for applicant 8
(9, 13), (9, 14), (9, 20), -- Skills for applicant 9
(10, 13), (10, 14), (10, 20); -- Skills for applicant 10

-- Drop the InterviewSchedules table if it already exists
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS InterviewSchedules;

-- Create the InterviewSchedules table
CREATE TABLE InterviewSchedules (
    interviewID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    applicantID INT,
    interviewDate DATE,
    interviewTime TIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (applicantID) REFERENCES Applicants(applicantID)
);

-- Insert 20 records into the InterviewSchedules table
INSERT INTO InterviewSchedules (applicantID, interviewDate, interviewTime)
VALUES 
(1, '2023-10-01', '09:00:00'),
(2, '2023-10-01', '10:00:00'),
(3, '2023-10-01', '11:00:00'),
(4, '2023-10-01', '13:00:00'),
(5, '2023-10-01', '14:00:00'),
(6, '2023-10-02', '09:00:00'),
(7, '2023-10-02', '10:00:00'),
(8, '2023-10-02', '11:00:00'),
(9, '2023-10-02', '13:00:00'),
(10, '2023-10-02', '14:00:00'),
(11, '2023-10-03', '09:00:00'),
(12, '2023-10-03', '10:00:00'),
(13, '2023-10-03', '11:00:00'),
(14, '2023-10-03', '13:00:00'),
(15, '2023-10-03', '14:00:00'),
(16, '2023-10-04', '09:00:00'),
(17, '2023-10-04', '10:00:00'),
(18, '2023-10-04', '11:00:00'),
(19, '2023-10-04', '13:00:00'),
(20, '2023-10-04', '14:00:00');
```

I have fixed all errors from this code, however it will not provide any output. I do not know where to go from here. All tables have been dropped/created, all error codes fixed, no output. I do not know what is causing this error, and would appreciate any help. This is new to me and I am learning, thanks.

Comment: What output do you expect and why? You drop tables, create tables and insert records. If you expect to see output, you should probably `SELECT` something from one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran your query in both MySQL workbench and MySQL cli. It works fine but one thing to notice is we need to select the database before running the script. So at the top of the script add the following line.
`use database_name;`